# this value of input field .val() not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code to check for any value on a given input and then add a simple class if the input has a value.

But in console i receive error that .val() is not a function?

my code is:

```
$.fn.tkFormControlMaterial = function(){
        this
            .blur(function () {
                if (this.val())
                    this.addClass('used');
                else
                    this.removeClass('used');
            })
            .after('<span class="ma-form-highlight"></span><span class="ma-form-bar"></span>');
    };
```

Comment: this seems to be also an issue in some HTML templates from 2015 I am trying to use now, thanks to your self-reply I was able to fix it

Answer (score 2):

bind will set you free

```
$.fn.tkFormControlMaterial = function(){
        this
            .blur(function () {
                if (this.val())
                    this.addClass('used');
                else
                    this.removeClass('used');
            }.bind(this))
            .after('<span class="ma-form-highlight"></span><span class="ma-form-bar"></span>');
    }.bind(this);
```

Comment: oh. you needed more bind. bind bind bind. I edited my answer

Comment: Then you need to include more context in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

If anyone needs a working sample of my own code above:

```
$.fn.tkFormControlMaterial = function(){
        $(this)
            .blur(function () {
                if ($(this).val())
                    $(this).addClass('used');
                else
                    $(this).removeClass('used');
            })
            .after('<span class="ma-form-highlight"></span><span class="ma-form-bar"></span>');
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use the "self" pattern.

```
var _self = this;
$.fn.tkFormControlMaterial = function(){
        _self
            .blur(function () {
                if (_self.val())
                    _self.addClass('used');
                else
                    _self.removeClass('used');
            })
            .after('<span class="ma-form-highlight"></span><span class="ma-form-bar"></span>');
    };
```